# For an algorithm with a time complexity of O(N+M), if M is always less than N, can we say the time complexity will be O(N)?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o

Give an algorithm with time complexity of O(N+M) and M<N.

Can we conclude O(N+M) => O(N+N) => O(2N) => O(N)

Will that be correct?

Comment: Yes, indeed we can.

Comment: @JoopEggen: I don't think that this remark is relevant or helpful.

Comment: @trincot you are right, no difference of opinion on my side. For independent quantities M and N certainly. But it says nothing of the relation between M and N. But I cannot think of any example with two factors like healthy people/infection rate. The curves of actual values of M and N might differ, though both linearly contribute to the time O(M+N). But I think Yves Daoust is right.

Comment: *"For independent quantities M and N certainly"*: @Joop, also for dependent quantities M and N certainly. As soon as it is certain that M < N, we can be certain it is O(N).

Comment: @YvesDaoust right

Comment: @trincot yes, _always_ O(N), and when an actual value of M increases time increases, the same for N, as O(N+M) tells. My sole intention was that in reality the number of M actual inputs might and N actual inputs to the algorithm might be bound by the algorithm itself. Like in a graph with nodes and edges. But I think Yves is right, and I should not have commented.

Answer (score 1):

`f(N, M) = O(N + M)` is by definition

```
E c, N0, M0: A N ≥ N0, M ≥ M0: f(N, M) ≤ c (N + M)
```

But by your hypothesis, M < N so that

```
E c, N0, M0: A N ≥ N0, M ≥ M0: f(N, M) ≤ c (N + M) < c 2N
```

and

```
E c', N0, M0: A N ≥ N0, M ≥ M0: f(N, M) ≤ c' N.
```